# Обрезка отображения меню

Tags: php, javascript, html, css3

Есть меню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выводится динамически php через ul/li и css 'column-count'. Нужно часть меню скрыть а при клике на кнопку раскрывать но это задача тривиальная давно решенная. Трудность возникла в том как обрезать отображение видимой части (нужно отображать только первые 5 в каждой колонке) но высота колонок меняется от категории к категории так как сами тексты подкатегорий везде разной высоты выходят (аяксом тоже не вариант подтягивать тогда поисковики видеть не будут). Может кто подскажет как обрезать отображение менюшки.
    `<?
     $cnt = count($subcats) / 3;
     $i = 0;
     ?>
     <ul>
     <? foreach ($subcats as $ssubcat): ?>
     <li class="<?= ($subcat == $ssubcat['cat'] ? 'selected' : '') ?>"><a
     href='/catalog/<?= $catalogname ?>/<?= $ssubcat['cat'] ?>/'><?        =$ssubcat['caption'] ?></a><span                                                        class="count_items"> (<?= $ssubcat['objects_count'] ?>)</span>,
      </li>
      <? endforeach ?>
      </ul>`

Comment: Покажите код генерирования меню

Comment: @KirillKorushkin вот. пробывал модифицировать код как то но ничего невышло т.к. к-во категорий разное и выводятся с разной длинной (выбирается к-во категорий делится на 3 колонки и они выводятся) то бишь каждый раз колонка получается разной высоты и нельзя четко отрезать ее.